# Graphviz doesn't understand GCC output

Tags: gcc, graphviz, dot

Running

```
gcc -fdump-tree-all-graph main.cpp -o main
```

should produce readable dot files. However, running

```
dot .\main.cpp.027t.einline -Tpng -o "main.png"
```

on any of the produced dot-files causes the error

```
Error: .\main.cpp.013t.cfg.dot: syntax error in line 1 near 'subgraph'
```

Gcc Version:  10.2.0
Graphviz version: 2.47.0

This problem persists for all C/C++ files. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Generic C++-Programm

```
int main() {}
```

creates 15 dot-Files, all of which look similar to:

```
subgraph "cluster_main" {
    style="dashed";
    color="black";
    label="main ()";
    fn_0_basic_block_0 [shape=Mdiamond,style=filled,fillcolor=white,label="ENTRY"];

    fn_0_basic_block_1 [shape=Mdiamond,style=filled,fillcolor=white,label="EXIT"];

    fn_0_basic_block_2 [shape=record,style=filled,fillcolor=lightgrey,label="{\<bb\ 2\>:\l\
|D.2331\ =\ 0;\l\
}"];

    fn_0_basic_block_3 [shape=record,style=filled,fillcolor=lightgrey,label="{\<bb\ 3\>:\l\
|\<L0\>:\l\
|return\ D.2331;\l\
}"];

    fn_0_basic_block_0:s -> fn_0_basic_block_2:n [style="solid,bold",color=blue,weight=100,constraint=true];
    fn_0_basic_block_2:s -> fn_0_basic_block_3:n [style="solid,bold",color=blue,weight=100,constraint=true];
    fn_0_basic_block_3:s -> fn_0_basic_block_1:n [style="solid,bold",color=black,weight=10,constraint=true];
    fn_0_basic_block_0:s -> fn_0_basic_block_1:n [style="invis",constraint=true];
}
}
```

Comment: `syntax error in line 1 near 'subgraph'` show `head main.cpp.013t.cfg.dot`. Or the whole file, if it's short

Comment: Works for me with Graphviz 2.43.0.

Comment: Which platform, looks like windows? Release version or Debug? Self compiled or packaged (from where) ? Works for me for a small program with dot version 2.47.0. Like KamilCuk said please show dot file and input cpp file.

Comment: `Head of the dot-File` Which dot file? There should be like 14 of them. `looks like this:` That's odd, the dotfile is invalid.. :/ . It should start with `digraph "main.c.013..." {`. Does recreating then result in the same dot files? Could you show the whole file - maybe there's a `digraph` keyword below? Could you move it like to a different filesystem and try then? Does the content of `main.cpp` matters, like, the problem is also with a `int main() {}` file?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a bit long for a comment

When using the program:

```
int main() {}
```

the command:

```
gcc -fdump-tree-all-graph main.cpp -o main
```

I get as one of the file: main.cpp.027t.einline.dotwith content:

```
digraph "main.cpp.027t.einline" {
overlap=false;
subgraph "cluster_main" {
        style="dashed";
        color="black";
        label="main ()";
        fn_0_basic_block_0 [shape=Mdiamond,style=filled,fillcolor=white,label="ENTRY"];

        fn_0_basic_block_1 [shape=Mdiamond,style=filled,fillcolor=white,label="EXIT"];

        fn_0_basic_block_2 [shape=record,style=filled,fillcolor=lightgrey,label="{\<bb\ 2\>:\l\
|_1\ =\ 0;\l\
}"];

        fn_0_basic_block_3 [shape=record,style=filled,fillcolor=lightgrey,label="{\<bb\ 3\>:\l\
|\<L0\>:\l\
|return\ _1;\l\
}"];

        fn_0_basic_block_0:s -> fn_0_basic_block_2:n [style="solid,bold",color=blue,weight=100,constraint=true];
        fn_0_basic_block_2:s -> fn_0_basic_block_3:n [style="solid,bold",color=blue,weight=100,constraint=true];
        fn_0_basic_block_3:s -> fn_0_basic_block_1:n [style="solid,bold",color=black,weight=10,constraint=true];
        fn_0_basic_block_0:s -> fn_0_basic_block_1:n [style="invis",constraint=true];
}
}
```

Used on Cygwin:

```
gcc (GCC) 10.2.0
```

So this looks all OK to me.